# “PowerPC applications are no longer supported” – Microsoft Office

Tags: macos, mac, ms-office

I am running on Mac OS X 10.8.2.

I have a licensed copy of Microsoft Office, and haven’t had a problem using it, until a recent update!

Since then, whenever I try to open it I get the following message:

> You can't open the application 'Microsoft Word' because PowerPC Applications are no longer supported

How do I resolve this, please?

Comment: What version of Office are you using?

Comment: @BartArondson MS-Office 2011

Comment: Can you check the exact version of Word? Go to Applications -> Microsoft Office -> Word and right click and press Get Info. It should be something like 14.3.8 or 14.3.9

Comment: I suggest you try to reinstall it.

Comment: Was the recent update an update to Office or Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1):

PowerPC applications were allowed on Intel Mac with Rosetta. Rosetta disappeared with Lion, if I remember well (There were 2 OS between Mavericks and Snow Leopard).
The solution is either get a new version of Microsoft Office, or downgrade your Mac OS X.

Comment: Although this answer is true in itself, it doesn't help the OP, it's a bit too general. The real issue here is that an application that worked fine suddenly turned into a PowerPC app after an update.

Comment: Indeed, now that he mentioned what version of Microsoft Office he has, it's quite a weird issue.

Comment: Office 2011 was released as Intel-only. I think Office 2008 was the last build that contained PowerPC binaries.